# How to apply PHP function to a column returned from CakePHP query

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

In my controller I am retrieving records from my institutions table with the following fields

```
 $params = array(
 'fields' => array(
 'Institution.id', 
 'Institution.name', 
 'Institution.about',              
 'Institution.picture'), 
 );

$institutions = $this->Institution->find('all',$params);
```

How can I prefix each 'Institution.picture' field with the full URL address, 'Institution.picture' itself only holds the name of the file.

I would also like to perform html_entity_decode() on each 'Institution.about' value from the returned set.

I know how to do this only without the framework if I make custom queries from scratch, then I would iterate each row and apply PHP functions to the field of interest. But is there a place in CakePHP (find or paginator) that I can specify such PHP manipulation on each field value from the returned set?

NOTE: I don't like to do this in the View, as I want to output it as json directly

Answer (score 3):

You can define [a virtualField](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#virtual-fields) for model:

```
public $virtualFields = array('image_url' => "CONCAT('/img/', Institution.picture)");

$params = array(
 'fields' => array(
 'Institution.id', 
 'Institution.name', 
 'Institution.about',              
 'Institution.picture',
 'Institution.image_url'), 
 );

$institutions = $this->Institution->find('all',$params);
```

Unfortunaly MySQL doesn't have a function to decode HTML entities. You may utilize an [afterFind() callback](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#afterfind) instead of virtualField. This lets you to decode entities as well as add a prefix.

Answer (score 2):

### CakePHP is php

Just iterate over the array and prepare it however you want:

```
$institutions = $this->Institution->find('all',$params);

$prefix = '/img/'; // <- define this
foreach ($institutions as &$row) {
    $row['Institution']['about'] = html_entity_decode($row['Institution']['about']);
    $row['Institution']['picture'] = $prefix . $row['Institution']['picture'];
}
```

If this is always required it can be applied to all finds via an [afterFind method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#afterfind) in the institution class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do it in the `View`. See [this example](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-a-data-view-with-view-files).

Answer (score 0):

[Hash::map](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Hash.html#_map) can be very useful here. By specifying path you can only modify slices of the set.